# Rspec routing error when redering ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, templates, rspec

Hey so i wrote a new feature and ran my test suit through Spork and i got a failing view test. this will be my first time looking at a view test so its a little confusing.

I am getting the following error

```
  ActionView::Template::Error:
   No route matches {:controller=>"employment_equity", :action=>"update_percentage_of_black_youth", :method=>:put, :scorecard_id=>123456, :id=>nil}
```

The view it is testing looks like this(i use sass and haml so that # is not a comment its referencing an id tag)

```
- if current_scorecard.base_charter_is? :transport_public_sector
  .left
    #percentage_of_employees_that_are_black_youth_input= f.field :percentage_of_employees_that_are_black_youth, :class => :percentage
  .left
    .auto_sum_link= link_to('Percentage from Details', update_percentage_of_black_youth_path(current_scorecard.id, @employment_equity.id), :method => :put, :remote => true)
```

As you can see i added the `:remote_true` to my `link_to` so that i can get ajax to fill in that filed on the fly. the thing is that its complaining that there is no route.

When i have it!

```
match '/scorecards/:scorecard_id/employment_equity/:id/update_percentage_of_black_youth', :controller => 'employment_equity', :action => 'update_percentage_of_black_youth', :method => :put, :as => 'update_percentage_of_black_youth'
```

Which then hits the ajax that basically fills in the field with the new value i work out in the model

```
$("#percentage_of_employees_that_are_black_youth_input input").val(<%= @employment_equity.percentage_of_employees_that_are_black_youth %>).effect("highlight", {color: "#C3EC97"}, 3000);
```

This all works in my dev environment and my unit tests all work just cant figure out why its not rendering because of a link that passes to ajax? any one found a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i talked to my neck beardy friend next to me to see if i was posing this question right and he figured out the problem my route was looking for an id

```
match '/scorecards/:scorecard_id/employment_equity/:id/update_percentage_of_black_youth'
```

and the test wasnt giving the `ID` because it wasnt saving the factoried class

```
No route matches {:controller=>"employment_equity", :action=>"update_percentage_of_black_youth", :method=>:put, :scorecard_id=>123456,  id=>nil}
```

sorry the error was super opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax isn't supported by default in RSpec / Capybara etc.  The reason being that javascript only functions in the browser.  Are you using Selenium or some other framework that allows for testing of javascript?

Comment: i didnt know that? we are using RSpec and Spork??

Comment: Yup, RSpec and Spork won't provide you with the ability to test the ajaxy functions. You definitely wanna look into Selenium or Jasmine if you want to test this part of your app

Comment: thanks for the info! i dont think any of our js is tested, i didnt know there was a rails way of testing it either. you rock socks